# How to remove the attribute from files and folders in a specified folder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I need to remove an attribute from files and folders in a specified folder, which is given as a parameter to the batch-file.

I tried to do this

```
for /f %%i in ('dir "%1" /A:H /B  ') do attrib -H %%i
```

but it does not work with `%1`

What am I doing wrong аnd how to correctly use "for" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

You should use `%1` or `"%~1"`: argument comes already parsed, so putting extra quotes may disrupt meaning.

`dir some_path /b ...` will return not-full qualified path names, so `%%i` will have not drive:path information.

Fast solution:

```
pushd %1
for /f %%i in ('dir /A:H /B') do attrib -H %%i
popd
```